# Getting GeoDjango working on RHEL

Tags: python, django, geodjango, spatialite

I'm working through dependency problems while installing GeoDjango dependencies on RHEL. I would love step-by-step instructions from anyone who has done this before. I'm transferring a working app from my Ubuntu development machine (where everything installed easily from packages) to a RHEL testing/staging server (packages ancient or unavailable).

- First I installed GEOS, GDAL, and PROJ.4 from source.
- Then I installed spatialite from source.
- Finally, I installed pysqlite from source, but it didn't like the existing RHEL sqlite3 libs (no extension loading support), so I used fresh static sqlite3 libs as described in the 1st answer of this question: http://bit.ly/lq9oV

Result:

- spatialite command line works
- manage.py syncdb works
- spatialite my.db < init_spatialite-2.3.sql works
- manage.py migrate works

BUT, when I request a page I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to load the SpatiaLite library extension "libspatialite.so.1" because: no such function: load_extension
```

I don't understand how syncdb and migrate commands work, but the http request fails.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed it on fedora (quite similar to RHEL) using yum packages and POSTGIS, check http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-install.html . If the required packages are not available for RHEL, you're stuck with installing everything from source. This is a bit harder in my opinion.

Looking at your error: it seems you're still using pysqlite without extension loading support. Did you rebuild both sqlite3 and pysqlite with extension loading support? And did you uninstall the original sqlite3 package (otherwise the wrong libraries might be used)?

Comment: I just gave up and convinced my supervisor to let us use Ubuntu Server LTS, where everything installs from packages without any problems.